# index extraction in tensorflow-js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am using `tensorflow-js` to do some image manipulation on the browser.

I have a tensor of type `bool`, and I want to extract the indexes of `true`/`1`  values from  it.

Is there a way I can do it without getting the whole tensor as an array via `Tensor.data()`?

At the moment I am doing something  like this:

```
let array = await tensor.data()
for(let i = 0; i <array.length;i++) {
 if (array[i]){
 //do Something
 };
};
```

but it takes too long on large tensors 600 ms plus on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

This still uses `tensor.data()` but it gives you a tensor which contains all the indices you want. (+1 because otherwise the multiplication always results in 0 wether the first value is 0 or not)

```js
tf.tidy(() => {

  const boolTensor = tf.randomUniform([10], 0, 2, "bool");
  boolTensor.print();

  const indices = tf.range(1, boolTensor.shape[0] + 1);
  //starting at 1 to prevent 0x0
  indices.print();

  const ones = boolTensor.cast("float32").mul(indices);
  ones.print();


  ind = Array.from(ones.dataSync()).filter(i => i > 0).map(i => i - 1);
  //map to go back to 0-indexed
  console.log(ind);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.10.0">
</script>
```

Comment: good idea but `ones.dataSync()` still parses the whole tensor  so the delay is still there